# Software keyboard is pushing the root view up

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm struggling with software(iOS/Android) keyboard which is pushing whole view up. I could not find any solution to prevent this behavior and could not find a workaround.

The layout I have is pretty simple chat outline:

```
Page {

    header: Toolbar {
    }

    ColumnLayoyt {
        ListView {
        }

        Pane {
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm currently trying in a nutshell:

```
Page {
    header: Toolbar {
        /// @hack Counterflow push
        topPadding: Qt.inputMethod.visible ? Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle.width : 0
    }

    ColumnLayoyt {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        ListView {
            id: feedView

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Pane {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.prefferedHeight: textArea.implicitHeight

            TextArea {
                id: textArea
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This eventually partially works but for some reason `Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle.y` is changing when textArea gets bigger and header.topPadding is eventually growing(gap is visually getting higher).

Anyway it looks like a hack and I'm still looking for a solution. How to deal with it? I hope that I'm just bad at googling these days, because such ui task seems pretty straightforward to me.